# Getting the font letter and color from a Styled Document/Text Pane

Tags: java, netbeans, styleddocument

Lately I have been using Style Constants, Styled Documents and Text Pane. I know that you can edit a part of the text that you highlight/select showing it in the code below

```
    StyledDocument doc = this.tpText.getStyledDocument();
    Style style = this.tpText.addStyle("stylish", null);
    StyleConstants.setForeground(style, color.BLACK);
    StyleConstants.setFontFamily(style, "Arial");
    doc.setCharacterAttributes(this.tpText.getSelectionStart(), this.tpText.getSelectionEnd() - this.tpText.getSelectionStart(), this.tpText.getStyle("stylish"), true);//This is the piece of code (last line) that will set all the attributes to the highlited text.
```

As an example, if the user highlights/selects "o worl" in "hello world", just the "o worl" will be changed to color black and the font letter will be Arial.

Now, my question is: how can you get the font letter and color from a highlihted/selected text? I want to know how can I save that in seperate variables (one for color and the other for the font letter).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after doing more research I found out the answer.

```
doc = this.tpText.getStyledDocument();
    Element element = doc.getCharacterElement(this.tpText.getSelectionStart());
    AttributeSet as = element.getAttributes();
    colour = StyleConstants.getForeground(as);
```

The only downside I see about this Style Constant method is that it will only recognize the first character attribute and overwrite/ignore the other ones. Maybe with a loop I can do it.